# Why Promise return an empty string?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have a function foo which makes an Ajax request. 
I tried returning the data from the callback and got the data with "xhr.onload" successfully but got an empty string("") with "xhr.onreadystatechange".

Could anyone tell me why??

Thank you very much!

```
function foo(url){

  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("GET",url,true);
//    xhr.onload = function(){
//     if(xhr.status == 200){             
//         resolve(xhr.responseText);
//         }else{
//          reject("false")
//         }
//    }
   xhr.send();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xhr.readyState && xhr.status == 200){             
          resolve(xhr.responseText);
      }else{
          reject("false")
      }

   }
 })

}

foo(url).then(function (data){
   console.log(data)
},function (err){
   console.log(err)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onreadystatechange` handler is incorrect. You need to check `readyState` for the value 4 (not just any truthy value), and you don't want to reject until `readyState` is 4:

```
  if(xhr.readyState === 4){
      if (xhr.status == 200) { // or xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300
          resolve(xhr.responseText);
      } else {
          reject("false")
      }
  }
```

But with modern browsers, you'd probably use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) instead, which already provides a promise. Just be sure not to make [these common mistakes](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) (that's a post on my anemic little blog).

As for why you were seeing what you were seeing, since you called `open` and `send` before attaching the handler apparently you didn't get the callback for `readyState` 1 (opened), so it looks like the first callback you got was when the headers were received (`readyState` 2), at which point `xhr.status` would be set — so you were resolving your promise, but of course, the request body hadn't been received yet.

Comment: Thanks for your help!